# css navigation div floating issues in firefox

Tags: css

I have a problem with the rendering of the navigation in Firefox. It is fine in Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox the whole navigation div floats right at the top right corner.

HTML:

```
<nav class="table">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Specialities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ffe;
}


ul#menu {
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 3em;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Can you please setup a http://jsfiddle.net with the issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dMN2/ here you go

Comment: What version of FF because it seems fine in FF9.

Comment: Just tested in FF10 which also looks fine to me.

Comment: well, just updated to 10, still the same, thanks for the help

Comment: perhaps you can add a screenshot of the issue or even better a live link?

Comment: I can confirm that the issue doesn't exist in FF 10/Ubuntu. Either your issue is OS specific or other CSS declarations are causing it.

Comment: Can't reproduce your browsers behavior, I'm using FF 10.0.1 on Win7 (64bit). Please add a screenshot of the issue. Maybe an extension you're using isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute margin you are setting it to "0 auto". With the information given I see the navigation in the left top corner in chrome also. And it is correct to see it there.

The attribute margin has the structure: top right bottom left //Thank you PeeHaa

It is the same if you use the following attributes: margin-right, margin-left, margin-top and margin-bottom. Those are to specify a particular margin.

If this doesn't answer your question, then you have to see if you have some

```
position:fixed;
```

or

```
position:absolute;
```

or

```
float:left/right;
```

for any tag into your html.

Comment: Also checking for some `position` or `float` on ANY element doesn't really help.

Comment: Thak you for the explenation.